# mongodb delete old chat

Tags: javascript, mongodb, node.js

I want to delete old chat logs, meaning any records besides the 10 latest.

Here's how I'm getting the latest:

```
collection.find({"chatroom" : chatroom}).limit(10).sort({ time: -1 })
```

How do I delete everything else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a query to get the 10th oldest and then delete the ones older than that.

```
var oldest = find({"chatroom" : chatroom}).limit(1).skip(10).sort({ time: -1 }).next();
remove({"chatroom" : chatroom, time : {$lt : oldest.time }})
```

Comment: Shouldn't be -> time : {$lt : oldest.time }

Comment: levhita: yep, fixed. Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate over each items of the result set and remove it individually if you get hold of the related documents through a proper filter.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a [capped collection](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Capped+Collections)?

Reserve enough space in `size` argument and set `max` to 10.

You might want to swtich `sort({ time: -1 })` with `sort({ $natural: -1 })` for better performance if you switch to a capped collection (where both orders would be the same I guess).

Comment: I don't really want to create a new collection for each chatroom

Answer (score -1):

How frequently you need to do this?
How many docs are we talking about?

One of the option:
move the latest 10 to some temp collection
empty the log collection
reinsert from the temp collection

This might not be the optimal solution.

Comment: Every time I get the 10 latest I dump the older ones. If this is too frequent then I can do it less as well.

Comment: You should keep a total count somewhere and then increment on each insert and decrement on each delete. You read this count to determine if you have more than 10 items. Otherwise, how are you checking?